# how mySql Data store in unique excel file that should be created dynamically

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpexcel, export-to-csv

I have a web page in which user was given certain input methods to fetch data from database. data will be displayed on web page.

I want to store data that user fetched data from my s-q-l database into an excel file.
command i'm using is given below

```
$excelquery1="SELECT * FROM excel12  INTO OUTFILE 'D:/Downloads/xyz.csv'";

$excelresult1=mysql_query($excelquery1);
```

it is running ok and data being fetched will be stored in a new file created in Downloads folder with a name xyz.csv

but user have to go manually to that location to check file.

how is it possible that user must be shown downloaded file in the download bar. + I also want to ask that if the xyz.csv is already present in the location when the query execute so in that scenario this query won't get execute saying `file already present`. so how to tackle this problem ?

how to give unique file name to the file that will be created..

Answer (score 0):

This is the main idea. You need to adequate the code to your need

```
$file="/path/to/file".date("YmdHis").".csv"; //file location
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Comment: do i have to make changes in header as well ? if yes so what changes would i have to make ?

Comment: how to retrieve the content of the file. In my case I did a simpe example of a file